# How to solve a Differential Equation with DSolve with Function Coefficient?

Tags: wolfram-mathematica, dsolve

Suppose I have

```
v[x_] = Square[1.453 Sech[x + 1]] + I  Sech[x + 1] Tanh[x + 1]
```

And I have to solve the equation:

```
mu1 u1[x] - u1''[x] - v[x] u1[x] == 0
```

for `u1[x]`. The conditions that are given are:

```
u1[-2] == 1, u1'[-2] == 0 .
```

I have tried `DSolve` but it shows errors:

> Solve::inex: Solve was unable to solve the system with inexact coefficients or the system obtained by direct rationalization of inexact numbers present in the system. Since many of the methods used by Solve require exact input, providing Solve with an exact version of the system may help.

How can I Solve this equation in Mathematical symbolically?

Comment: after giving the input :                                            sol = DSolve[{mu1 u1[x] - u1''[x] - v[x] u1[x] == 0, u1[-2] == 1, 
   u1'[-2] == 0}, u1, x]  i got : " Solve::inex: Solve was unable to solve the system with inexact coefficients or the system obtained by direct rationalization of inexact numbers present in the system. Since many of the methods used by Solve require exact input, providing Solve with an exact version of the system may help. >>" and the output shows exactly the input

Comment: @MashriqAhmed In the definition of `v` what do you mean by `Square` ? Is it the second power (`^2`) or the square root (`Sqrt`) ?

Comment: Square is not a function. Use ^2.

Comment: i used ^2. But its shows the same error: "Solve::inex: Solve was unable to solve the system with inexact coefficients or the system obtained by direct rationalization of inexact numbers present in the system. Since many of the methods used by Solve require exact input, providing Solve with an exact version of the system may help. >>" i am so stuck with this problem.

Comment: @ b.gatessucks. its not Square, its (^2)

Answer (score 1):

This simpler version solves:

```
sol = DSolve[{mu1*u1[x] - u1''[x] - Cos[x]* u1[x] == 0,
    u1[-2] == 1,
    u1'[-2] == 0},
   u1, x];

GraphicsRow[Table[Plot[Evaluate[u1[x] /. sol], {x, 0, 20},
   PlotRange -> All], {mu1, 1, 3}]]
```

[image]

But your equation with v included has problems, presumably mathematical:

```
DSolve[{mu1*u1[x] - u1''[x] -
    ((1.453*Sech[x + 1])^2 + I*Sech[x + 1]*Tanh[x + 1])* u1[x] == 0,
  u1[-2] == 1,
  u1'[-2] == 0},
 u1, x]
```

Comment: The equation of v[x] is V[x]=(A sech(x ±D/2 ))^2+i B sech(x ±D/2 )tanh(x ±D/2),
where A=sqrt(2+(B^2) /9) and D is the separation between
the two potentials. This is the equation of a Potential. Can this differential equation be solved for u1[x]???